# Different hosting site for serving static content using Django?

Tags: django

I am all new to this web thing and learning Django framework. What I needed to know was, can i serve my both apps and static files to different hosting sites? I hope i have made my question clear, if not please ask.

Comment: Do you mean doing ajax requests across different hosts? Or static files vs application? The options and best solutions depends on exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Yes, static vs application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. You can find more information in the Django docs for ["Managing static files"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and ["Deploying static files"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/). It just takes a little configuration of your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Thank you! By the way will the page slow down to load?

Comment: That depends almost entirely on your hosting setup. If your static file host offers good speed, then it should be faster than serving both from the same place. The browser will be able to request the files directly from your static-file server, rather than going through your application server and adding to its load. Plus, with the right configuration, a static file server should be much faster than one set up to serve an application. So, your page should be at least as fast if not faster by separating the two. // Also, just a reminder to select the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm reading you correctly, I think you're asking about best practices on serving static files separately from your Django app.

Best practices, in my mind, would be to server DJango behind a proxy such as Nginx. This would let Nginx server static files, and pass application requests to DJango. Your Django app can be run as a fcgi process.

Here are some docs on that topic:

1. [Nginx + Django with fcgi](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx).
2. [Nginx + Django with uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)
3. [SO question/answer on Nginx + Django with uWSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329807/django-app-deployment-on-nginx)

Hope that helps rather than confuses.

Answer (score -2):

Technically, yes. However (a) this will likely make your site much slower (b) many browsers will refuse to load resources from a different host than that serving the html, due to implementing CORS (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). You'll need to enable appropriate headers and options on the static server to make it work.

The normal thing is to serve all of your content from the same hosting service, except in so far as you use a CDN.

Comment: Thank you. What if host the static files from the same service but from dedicated server? Will that too slow it down?

Comment: @user2397891 Why wouldn't you host both on a dedicated server? But yes, that will likely be fine.

Comment: I don't think this a question about ajax requests that would necessitate the use of CORS.

Comment: Okay. Can you please suggest on some tutorials on how to serve django on apache + mod_wsgi and statics on nginx + gunicorn?

Comment: @fideloper I don't see how this is about ajax requests.

Comment: @user2397891 Are you joking? Gunicorn is for hosting dynamic content servers like django. You can just use nginx directly for the static content.

Comment: @Maric - From the linked Wikipedia article `Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows Javascript on a web page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain`. I don't get why you mentioned that in your answer. Shouldn't be an issue for serving static content separately from the application.

Comment: @fideloper It will interfere with any attempt to load resources from multiple hosts. It's a browser feature, so simply referring to a standard (which wikipedia is not) is not that useful in practice. The page is, I guess, fairly seriously misleading. It's not that at all: it's a mechanism which prevents pages from loading content from other hosts, unless those hosts explicitly allow it.