# django nginx uWSGI can't working fine

Tags: python, django, nginx

When i run with [Django app deployment on nGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329807/django-app-deployment-on-nginx) my scripts in nginx webserver i ended with following error..when i tried with new Django also showing same error

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9 (64bit) on [Thu Nov 14 08:13:25 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) on 30 October 2013 03:04                                                                                        :04
os: Linux-2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 17:19:38 UTC 2013
nodename: cderamaster.alp.com
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /root/uwsgi-1.9
detected binary path: /root/uwsgi-1.9/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 87059
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uWSGI http bound on :3506 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 8445)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:45386 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Sep 27 2013, 05:16:16)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red                                                                                         Hat 4.4.7-3)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads                                                                                         ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xdd6e20
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72632 bytes (70 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
added /Genie3501/genie/ to pythonpath.
ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 8444, cores: 1)
```

I am using scripting only not for webapplication.its for API.

Please help me to fix the problem..

Thanks for your attention...

Comment: please post uWSGI config, you have a pythonpath problem

Comment: ./uwsgi --http 10.0.0.13:3550 --master 1 --workers 10 --disable-logging --daemonize /tmp/daemonize.log --pidfile /tmp/pidfile.txt --vacuum --max-requests 100 --gid 500 --uid 500 --virtualenv /root/genie/bin/python --pythonpath /Genie3503/genie/genie --module wsgi  this is my uWSGI config  @roberto

Comment: virtualenv takes the virtualenv dir not a path to the python binary. If you do not use virtualenvs remove it